# Divisibility of cubes by 7

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Show that if if $x^3+y^3=z^3$ for some $x,y,z$ $ \in \mathbb{Z}$ then one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by $7$.

I'm stuck on this problem. I know that for any integer $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $[n^3 \pmod{7}]$ $\in\{0,1,6\}$. So I think of breaking it into cases:

Case 1) $n^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$

Case 2) $n^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$

Case 3) $n^3 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$

I'm not sure how to proceed with any of the above cases.

Edit:

In order to proceed, one needs to know the following proposition:

Let a,b be integers. Let p be a prime. If p|ab then p|a or p|b. If b=a then p|ab implies p|a.

Therefore for the first case, if $7|z^3$ then $7|z$ as 7 is prime. The other two cases follow similarly

The proof of the proposition is the following:

Assume $p|ab$ and p does not divide a. Then if I assume $gcd(p,a)=d>1$ Then it follows that d |a and d|p. As p is prime, d =1 or p. If d =p then p|a, which is a contradiction so $gcd(p,b)=1$ and so $p|b$

Comment: Can any triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c \in \{0,1,6\}$ satisfy $a+b=c$?

Comment: Also, change your title.  It's waaay too vague.

Comment: @Dzoooks (0,0,0)?

Comment: Yep, and so they're all divisible by 7 in that case.  Now do the (two) others.

Answer (score 4):

You've done all the work... simply observe that $$x^3+y^3=z^3\implies x^3+y^3\equiv z^3\pmod 3$$ Thus, the sum of two residues has to be another residue. This only works for $0+1=1, 0+6=6, 0+0=0$ and $6+1\equiv 0$. Notice that every possibility contains a number $\equiv 0\bmod 7$.

---

*Sidenote* $\ $ This is a nice exercise in order to practice modular arithmetic, however Fermat's Last Theorem tells us that there is no solution for $z\not= 0\implies 7\mid z$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Also there’s $0+0=0$, though I didn’t downvote

Comment: That's right @J.W.Tanner. Thanks for pointing that out ;)